# Can I swap Excel4 with Excel12?

Tags: c, excel, api, excel-addins

In the Excel C API, what is the difference between the Excel4 and Excel12 functions?

From the on-line documentation I read that Excel12 is the most recent version, but there is now mention about possible differences.

Can I substitute all Excel4 calls with Excel12 in C++ code?

Thank you.

---

Excel 2010, Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Excel12 function are only available from Excel 2007 and up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687835.aspx

Comment: I know. Do they work in the same way? Can I substitute one with the other, without any visible consequences?